# Compiling data from two different levels of an XML WAPI reply

Tags: groovy

I have a WAPI response I have to go through to get information on two different levels and put it all together.

The response looks like this (there's more info in it than this but this is all we care about):

```
 <SearchResponse>
      <SearchStatus>Success</SearchStatus>
      <Itinerary>
           <SellerCode>
                AA
           </SellerCode>
           <DisplayPrice>
               123.45
           </DisplayPrice>
           <EligibleTypes>
                <Student>
                     true
                </Student>
                <Youth>
                     true
                </Youth>
                <Adult>
                     false
                </Adult>
           </EligibleTypes>
      </Itinerary>
       <Itinerary>
          <SellerCode>
              XC
          </SellerCode>
           <DisplayPrice>
                234.99
           </DisplayPrice>
           <EligibleTypes>
                <Student>
                     true
                </Student>
                <Youth>
                     true
                </Youth>
                <Adult>
                     false
                </Adult>
           </EligibleTypes>
      </Itinerary>
 </SearchResponse>
```

There are dozens of these Itineraries. What I need to do is:
For each eligible type (Student=true for example) I need to find out:

1. How many the total number of each eligible type, Student, Youth, Adult, etc.
2. The cheapest DisplayPrice and SellerCode for that cheapest price for EACH eligible type.

The output would look like this:

```
STUDENT:23:$110.00:AA | YOUTH:50:$300.00:XC
```

Cheapest price, that's easy but I'm totally lost on this one because of the different levels. Any help on this one is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your XML here `files/wapi.xml` and this code:

```
class XmlWapiTest {
    static main(args) {
        File file = new File('files/wapi.xml')

        Node xml = new XmlParser().parse(file)
        List<String> types = ['Student', 'Youth', 'Adult']

        types.each { type ->
            List typeList = xml.findAll { itinerary -> itinerary."EligibleTypes"."$type".text().toBoolean() }
            int size = typeList.size()
            def lowestMap = typeList.collectEntries { itinerary ->
                [(itinerary."SellerCode".text().trim()): itinerary."DisplayPrice".text().toFloat()]
            }.min { it.value }


            println "${type.toUpperCase()}:$size:${lowestMap?.key}:${lowestMap?.value}"
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the next output:

```
STUDENT:2:AA:123.45
YOUTH:2:AA:123.45
ADULT:0:null:null
```

**EDIT 1:**

Based on your comments we need to change part for `lowestMap`:

```
def temporaryMap = [:]

typeList.each { itinerary ->
    String key = itinerary."SellerCode".text().trim()
    Float value = itinerary."DisplayPrice".text().toFloat()
    if (temporaryMap.containsKey(key)) {
        if (temporaryMap.get(key) > value) temporaryMap[key] = value
    } else temporaryMap[key] = value
}

def lowestMap = temporaryMap.min { it.value }
```

Comment: This isn't giving me the cheapest price.

Comment: In my run here I am getting this: STUDENT:196:WN:302.1 the other types are the same as that.  The count is correct. Here are the cheapest prices by seller code: [AA:160.34, NK:198.38, UA:285.30, AS:286.20, WN:289.80, B6:310.20, SY:418.80, 0M:543.40]

Comment: So, does it mean what SellerCode is not unique? I don’t know exactly your data structure, if SellerCode is not unique, then my code will not work properly for cheapest price.

Comment: Each Itinerary node has a unique SellerCode subnode but there can be dozens, even hundreds of Itinerary nodes.

Comment: Please, check EDIT 1 section in my answer.

Comment: @Sulteric Even if you are not very close, please add what you have tried next time.  It usually makes writing an answer easier.